# Spell checking errors and not finding red underlines in page

Tags: branding, custom-masterpage, check-in, spellchecker

In SharePoint 2010 custom master pages is there an element that controls the spell checker's red underline in rich text edited pages?

When I try to check-in a page with errors I see a number of them listed in the check-in dialog box. I cancel check-in and look in the editing area of the page for errors but don't see any red underlines.

Lost on this and it is the only thing I still have to fix before authors can be trained.

Answer (score 0):

For spelling errors SharePoint wraps the text in a span with "ms-spellcheck-error" as the class.  I would check to ensure nothing is preventing that class from displaying correctly.

Comment: I have noticed that taxonomy fields and people pickers sometimes is the cause, their hidden fields get's validated (but since they are hidden, the decoration is invisible on the page)

Comment: Seems that .ms-spellcheck-error was not pointing at the background image right. is now working